# How to Paste the Data into Non-Adjacent Columns in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, copy-paste

Could it possible to paste a Selection of Data into Non-Adjacent Columns

For Example:
I need to copy columns W,X,Z and Paste these columns into C,D,G Columns in one command

```
        Dim OldRange As Range:
        Set OldRange = Union(SelectedSheet.Range("W4:X" & LastRow), SelectedSheet.Range("Z4:Z" & LastRow))
        OldRange.Copy

        Dim NewRangeForOld As Range
        Set NewRangeForOld = Union(SelectedSheet.Range("C" & TransferedDataLastRow), SelectedSheet.Range("D" & TransferedDataLastRow), SelectedSheet.Range("G" & TransferedDataLastRow))
        NewRangeForOld .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: You can't paste into a non-contiguous range.  You'll need to first copy W:X and then Z

Comment: Why do you think you need to copy those columns in one command? What's the issue with copying them with two commands? Please clarify (I will  be happy to revoke my close vote after seeing a reasonable explanation).